# Persistent local data on the clientside in Meteor

Tags: session, meteor, reactjs, local-storage, persistent-storage

I am working with Meteor + React.
The question is about **correct way** to store persistent data locally on the client.

Let's say I have a component `List` with list of 5 articles:

```
export default class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        <li><a href='/article1'>Article 1</li>
        <li><a href='/article2'>Article 2</li>
        <li><a href='/article3'>Article 3</li>
        <li><a href='/article4'>Article 4</li>
        <li><a href='/article5'>Article 5</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Then let's say, that `Article` component should be rendered for routes like `/articleN`.

```
export default class Article extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <main>
        ..
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

**My goal** is to build a `VisitedList` component, which containes the list of already visited articles.

**My solution** uses the `persistent-session` package ([link](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session)). There are several packages like `persistent-minimongo` but I need a **stable** solution. More than 27k downloads of `u2622:persistent-session` made me think that it is quite stable. But again - I don't know for sure. Now about my solution.

In the `Article` component in the `ComponentDidMount` part I am working with persistent session variables like with array elements. Let me explain. First, I check if a `Session` variable with `key` `historyLength` exists. If not (that means that user visits article page for the first time), I set a new persistent variable called `historyLength` and equals 0. I use this variable to store length of my history selfmade "array".

Then I check if current article is in the history, and if not - I add it to history. Adding to history in fact - is setting a new persistent variable with `key` `historyN`, where `N = historyLength`.

It is simplier to look at the code, rather than my attempts to explain it in words.

So the code for the `Article` component:

```
export default class Article extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
          if (Session.get('historyLength')) {
              console.log('history exists');
          } else {
              Session.setPersistent('historyLength', 0);
              console.log('first history init');
          }

          var articleInHistory = false;

          for(i = 0; i < Session.get('historyLength'); i++) {
              var key = 'history' + i;
              if(Session.equals(key, this.props.articleName)) {
                  articleInHistory = true;
                  console.log('already in history:', i);
              } else {
                  console.log(i, 'product is not in history');
              }
          }
          if(!articleInHistory) {
              var newHistoryKey = 'history' + (Session.get('historyLength'));
              Session.setPersistent(newHistoryKey, this.props.articleName);

              var curHistoryLength = Session.get('historyLength');
              Session.setPersistent('historyLength', curHistoryLength + 1);
          }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <main>
        ..
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

This code works correct. I can access `Session.get('historyLength')` in any component and then get names of visited articles with `for` loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < Session.get(historyLength); i++) {
  let key = "history" + i;
  console.log(key, Session.get(key));
}
```

Finally the `VisitedList` component:

```
export default class VisitedList extends Component {
  renderVisited() {
    var visitedArticles = [];
    for(i = 0; i < Session.get(historyLength); i++) {
      let key = "history" + i;
      visitedArticles.push(Session.get(key));
    }

    return visistedArticles.map((each) => {
      return <li> {each} </li>
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        { this.renderVisited() }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

My question is: **Is my solution correct way to store and use local persistent data?** This example is simple and not from the real project, but it shows the problem and the solution of the problem.

I am going to build such history block in my project and a shopping cart. So if there is more efficient, fast and proper way to solve this problem, than I want know about it before I start. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor `Session` use is somewhat discouraged these days (since it pollutes the global namespace, it can be difficult to keep track of its contents and keep it clean, etc.). Since [u2622:persistent-session](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) works with Meteor's `Session` object, I don't think this will be the most future proof option. Since you're using react, have you considered instead using [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) for your client side state management? Redux is quickly (if it hasn't already) becoming the most popular application state container in the javascript/react space. Redux by itself isn't persistent, but there are several add-on libraries that will give you persistence capabilities, like [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).

Comment: thank you for your answer! actually I saw mentions about Redux, but don't know anything about it. The reason for using redux in normal react apps is obvious: components have only state, that is disposable. but using meteor we have different other instruments, like Session. I am really limited in time, so to start over with new technology (redux) will take at least couple of days, and as I can see redux is another different way to build apps, while I already have working version of project.

Comment: I want to know ways to implement something like history block or shopping cart in meteor app using its basic tools or small packages.